# How big can the null space of $A^TSA$ be?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ be a $m\times n$ matrix with full rank (and $m\geq n$, so that it has no null space).  I understand that if $S$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix, then $A^TSA$ also has full rank (since $\langle A^TSAx,x\rangle = \langle S Ax,Ax\rangle > 0$ when $Ax\not=0$).

I am asking about the case that $S$ is not positive definite, but it is symmetric and invertible.  How big can the null space of $A^TSA$ be?  Is it possible that $A^TSA$ has a two dimensional nullspace?  A two hundred dimensional nullspace?  It seems to me that there should exist such examples, but I am unable to find them.

Comment: Ah, yes, I mean to say that $n\geq m$.

Comment: Yes, that's right, $A$ is tall and skinny and its columns are linearly independent.  I'll fix the question to match the custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give the answer in terms of rank, with scalars in $\mathbb R$. It's worth pointing out that if we had special structure, e.g. commutativity where $AA^T S = SAA^T$ then $\text{rank}\big(A^TSA\big) = n$.  Outside of special structure, we can only bound the rank.

applying **Frobenius Rank Inequality**
$n + (n-m) =\text{rank}\Big(A^T S\Big) + \text{rank}\Big(SA\Big)- \text{rank}\Big(S\Big)\leq \text{rank}\Big(A^T SA\Big)$
so there is a lower bound on rank of $\max\big(0,2n -m\big)$.

Unfortunately one cannot improve on this inequality in general. E.g. consider bipartite

$S := \begin{bmatrix}\mathbf 0 &B \\ B^T &\mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$
with invertible $B$ and suppose $A:=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf I_n  \\ \mathbf 0\end{bmatrix}$.  Notice $2n=m$.  Then
$\mathbf 0 = A^TBA$ and
$0 = n + (n-2n) = n + (n-m) \leq \text{rank}\Big(A^T SA\Big)$
which is to say that Frobenius's Rank Inequality is met with equality.