# Prove a matrix $A Q^{-1}A^T$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be $m \times n$ matrix with linearly independent rows and let $Q$ be a square matrix of type $n \times n$ and positive definite. Assume that $Q$ is invertible. Show that $A Q^{-1} A^T$ is invertible.

I know that if the rows of $A$ are linearly independent so that $AA^T$, which is $m \times m$ matrix, is invertible. Proof can be found in [Prove](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1151491/under-what-conditions-is-aat-invertible)

But in this case, I don't have any idea to begin.

Comment: $B$? $Q$? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I have edited, my typo.

Comment: I remember working with this problem. I think rank of $AQ^{-1}$A' is equal to rank of $AA'$, thus it is invertible

Comment: Ok I will try. Thank you.

Comment: @Lee but how to prove rank of $AQ^{-1}A^T$ is equal to rank of $AA^T$?

Comment: rank of $AQ^{-1}$ = rank of $A$

Comment: closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3724212/how-big-can-the-null-space-of-atsa-be/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need further hypotheses (e.g. $Q$ being positive definite). The claim is wrong as stated. Example: $A=\pmatrix{ 1 & 1}$ and $Q=\pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1}$ yields $A Q^{-1}A^T=\pmatrix{0}$